# How to work with Authentication in Framework7 Vue

Tags: javascript, cordova, vue.js, vuejs2, html-framework-7

I am using the latest Framework7 Vue Webpack starter pack.

My default page ('/') is a login page.  My plan was to run a xhr request as soon as any page in the app is requested.

1. So I tried putting the isLoggedIn() call in the onF7Ready(f7). If logged in I thought I would use this to take the user to the home screen - self.$f7router.navigate('/home/'); else I would take the user to the Login page. Then I learnt the $f7router is only accessible in the Route Components.
2. Then I thought I will put the isLoggedIn() check in each and every page's pageInit(). So I tried putting that code in the login.vue file in

   `on: {
   pageInit(e) {`

   The $f7router is available here but the self.$f7router.navigate('/home/'); does not work. The same self.$f7router.navigate('/home/'); however does work if I use it in one of the dummy methods in the same login.vue file.

Even if the above code did work, there must be a better way of checking if a user is logged in and then do things in a much better way then I am doing. All my routes except for the  ('/') require authentication.

Can anyone tell me how I should approach this very standard issue? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I am checking in ajax requests, if a receive an 401 it means that I should redirect to login page.

Answer (score 1):

I found that the self.$f7router.navigate is not available in the pageInit(), however, it is available in the pageBeforeIn() and other functions that follows the pageInit().

Sidenote: I found pageInit() to be quite dangerous for this particular use case because everytime you navigate to this page the page is going to run the AJAX request not just when the App is first accessed.

Comment: The documentation is a real struggle for this. Everything I need to do is a battle.